# Toggle functionality between a textbox and dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

I have a Dropdown which contains 2 values - Name and Gender

If user selects Name in the dropdown, then a textbox(default control) is displayed to allow text entry.
However if the User selects Gender in the dropdown, then a dropdown is displayed to allow user to select from 2 values - Male and Female.

I want to rewrite this behavior using Knockout js. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="switch">
<option value="option">Select Option...</option>
<option value="name">Name </option>
<option value="gender">Gender </option>
</select>
<span id="name-input" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="name"></span>
<span id="gender-dropdown" style="display:none">
<select id="gender">
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
</select></span>

$("#switch").change(function () {
  switch($("#switch").val()) {
    case "name":
      $("#name-input").css("display", "inline")
      $("#gender-dropdown").css("display", "none")
      break
    case "gender":
      $("#name-input").css("display", "none")
      $("#gender-dropdown").css("display", "inline")
      break
    default:
      $("#gender-dropdown").css("display", "none")
      $("#name-input").css("display", "none")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to complete all [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) on the official site. These tutorials won't take long but they are really useful for beginners.

Your task may be completed with built-in bindings only and the simple one-variable view model.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  selectedOption: ko.observable()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select id="switch" data-bind="value: selectedOption">
<option value="option">Select Option...</option>
<option value="name">Name </option>
<option value="gender">Gender </option>
</select>
<span id="name-input" data-bind="visible: selectedOption() == 'name'"><input type="text" id="name"></span>
<span id="gender-dropdown" data-bind="visible: selectedOption() == 'gender'">
<select id="gender">
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
</select></span>
```

Comment: Thank You. This helps. I am on the tutorials now.